# Pass object reference of custom element to another custom element via drag and drop

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have 2 custom elements, A and B. I currently have the elements set up so that I can drag A and drop it onto B, and a copy of A is added as a child of B. I don't want a copy of A to be the child though. I want A itself to be the child.

How can I do this?

I'm using dataTransfer to send HTML to B, and then B is constructing a copy of A. I'm happy to use something instead of dataTransfer as long as it gets the job done. I do not want to use any libraries.

The CoffeeScript:

```
class A extends HTMLElement
    constructor: () ->
        super()
        this.setAttribute 'draggable','true'
        this.setAttribute 'ondragstart','drag(event)'
    drag: (event) ->
        event.stopPropagation()
        event.dataTransfer.setData 'symbol', this.outerHTML

class B extends A
    constructor: ->
        super()
        this.setAttribute 'ondrop','drop(event)'
        this.setAttribute 'ondragover','allowDrop(event)'
    drop: (event) ->
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopPropagation()
    data = event.dataTransfer.getData 'symbol'
        template = document.createElement 'template'
        template.innerHTML = data
        try
            event.target.myFunctionToAddChild template.content.firstChild
    allowDrop: (event) ->
        event.preventDefault()
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be impossible to do.

Instead, give all elements a unique ID, and then pass the ID via the dataTransfer method. That way, the receiving element can find the element by its ID and reference it directly.

Get unique ID via yield:

```
getUniqueID = ->
    num = 0
    loop
        num += 1
        yield 'Unique_ID:' + num
    return
```

Send ID:

```
drag: (event) ->
    event.stopPropagation()
    event.dataTransfer.setData "Unique_ID", this.id
```

Receive ID and find element:

```
drop: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    event.stopPropagation()
    Unique_ID = event.dataTransfer.getData 'Unique_ID'
    element = document.getElementById(Unique_ID)
```